# Custom Mongoose Population

Tags: node.js, mongoose, microservices

I have a microservices architecture (NodeJS) where the services have their own database (mongo). Each database has an userId reference (from another microservice). My question is if I can (and how) make a custom mongoose population function, where I can give it a field name and a function that iterates trough the field name and returns an object.

```
Items.find({}).populate('userId', getObj)

getObj(userId) {
 return "object promise";
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? It sounds like you want to only select items where `userId` matches a particular value, in which case you should use [`match`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-populate).

Comment: I am trying to get the User from another process, let's say an API. I have a key in Items with userIds, and an API endpoint /users/:id which responds with the User object, and I want to populate the userIds values with the responses from the API.

Comment: So instead of populating the document using the database, you want to populate it with results from an API-call?

Comment: As I said in the initial question, the services have their own database. Users in the users service connected to the user_db, items in the items service connected to the item_db. The items belong to a user and they need to be linked somehow, either trough APIs, eventbus, etc.

Comment: Population in the context of Mongoose isn't meant for something like that, it's meant for models that exist within the same database, and are linked together through their schema. So the item service needs to find the item(s), and somehow resolve the userId('s). However, that _somehow_ falls beyond the scope of Mongoose.